# Unable to install test flight builds iOS 8

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

Thanks for the time, I am using iOS 8 and test flight to install test builds. When I attempt to install I receive an error that states:

"Could not install (app name) wide.profile.inactive" <--- this is not a bundle ID That I have ever used.

Answer (score 0):

Is the provisioning profile you build the app with valid? 
Does the profile contain the device number(UDID) that the app is being installed on?

You probably know this, but to check go to: 
https://developer.apple.com/ -> Member Center -> Certificates -> Provisioning Profiles

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the @3x iPhone 6 app icon from your app bundle.